# Pip install without progress bars

Tags: python, pip, progress-bar, circleci

In my Django application I have a circle.yml file that runs 'pip install -r requirements/base.txt'. When I push up code, and check the CircleCI logs when there is an error, its hard to get to because there are so many dependencies and as of pip6 they started showing progress bars for the installations. Because of that it get busy pretty quick. I read on pip's github page that a few people were requesting a flag to the install command to remove the progress bars, but continue to show everything else like exceptions. something like

`pip install --no-progress-bar foo`

https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/4194. It doesn't look like this has been released yet though. Is there any way to currently do this without using --**no-cache-dir** ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That PR was merged and is available on the latest stable build (pip 10.0.1 at the time of writing). Just do:

`pip install foo --progress-bar off`

Other args are available. See the [pip install docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/).

Comment: Thanks, this helped me when working with Portainer web terminals -- I would get broken connections during installs, and removing the progress bars solved them.

Comment: Can also set `PIP_PROGRESS_BAR` environment variable, which won't break older pips.

Comment: It's sad that `pip install -q ...` (quiet flag) doesn't automatically disable this progress bar.

Answer (score 7):

Use [pip config](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/) to turn these off by default:

```
pip config --user set global.progress_bar off
```

(perhaps remove `--user` for admins, or use replace with `--venv` for virtualenv)

Comment: --site instead of --venv (venv seems like an old deprecated config)